# Tagging support

Tags: java, tags, tagging

We would like to add the "tagging" support to the existing websites which uses Java. This tagging support will be used to find the "tagged" items .

Are there any libraries that support my use case ?

Comment: yep!! .. that is correct .. somehow I couldnt make it .. Thanks .. I will do tht :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use something like Hibernate. This is very similar to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172950/add-external-relationship-tagging-to-existing-hibernate-entities), which will give you a good start.